# Image not uploading

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

It is when I select the upload files button that the file goes red and doesn’t upload.

[image: Getting error when i upload file]

Comment: Did you check directory permission of `media`?

Comment: yes all are 0777.

Comment: and what is the ownership of directory? is it `www-data` or anything else?

Comment: @ImrozAnjum install this extension after chck it : https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?